# How to create an index on a CONCAT("string" ,column) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table where id is primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col1 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

I have another table t2 which is joining table t1 as

```
t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON CONCAT("USER_", t1.id) = t2.user_id
```

I want to create an index which has CONCAT("USER_", t1.id) values indexed in any order.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX ((CONCAT('user_',id) DESC);
```

but it is giving error.
I have followed official documentation of mysql.

**Note : I do not want to create a new CONCAT("user_", id) column.**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes

Comment: Work in the other direction, change `t2.user_id` so that it does NOT require a constant prefix of ``USER_`` which adds no benefits but does deliver disadvantages. `t2.user_id` should be an integer, not a string

Comment: I understand that but this is a legacy system and I cannot change tables. Is there is no way to create index like that ?

Comment: To solve this issue you will be changing some tables, you need generated columns, then indexes.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Generated column cannot refer to auto-increment column. And id is Auto-increment column.

Answer (score 2):

> InnoDB supports secondary indexes on virtual generated columns. 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

In 5.7(onward) you can use a generated column, then index that column. e.g.

Here is an example of taking the integer out of the string to create an efficient join:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE myusers (
>     id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
>   , name varchar(255) default NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO myusers (`name`) VALUES ('Imelda'),('Hamish'),('Brandon'),('Amity'),('Jillian'),('Lionel'),('Faith'),('Dai'),('Reed'),('Molly');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>     id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
>   , user_id VARCHAR(20)
>   , ex_user_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (0+substring(user_id,6,20))
>   , password varchar(255)
>   , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>   , INDEX idx_ex_user_id (ex_user_id)
> ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (`user_id`,`password`) VALUES 
>  ('user_1','PYX68BIC9RD')
> ,('user_2','LPY07EIN0UA')
> ,('user_3','UGC24TKI3JL')
> ,('user_4','YQU18ALB8YA')
> ,('user_5','DEL56AGR6AD')
> ,('user_6','YQN87UOB0PO')
> ,('user_7','CPC15JFU6MC')
> ,('user_8','MWC40ZWD2EE')
> ,('user_9','HEB34QQH0UM')
> ,('user_10','GVP36PLP5PW')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from myusers
> inner join mytable on myusers.id = mytable.ex_user_id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    | id | user_id | ex_user_id | password   
> -: | :------ | -: | :------ | ---------: | :----------
>  1 | Imelda  |  1 | user_1  |          1 | PYX68BIC9RD
>  2 | Hamish  |  2 | user_2  |          2 | LPY07EIN0UA
>  3 | Brandon |  3 | user_3  |          3 | UGC24TKI3JL
>  4 | Amity   |  4 | user_4  |          4 | YQU18ALB8YA
>  5 | Jillian |  5 | user_5  |          5 | DEL56AGR6AD
>  6 | Lionel  |  6 | user_6  |          6 | YQN87UOB0PO
>  7 | Faith   |  7 | user_7  |          7 | CPC15JFU6MC
>  8 | Dai     |  8 | user_8  |          8 | MWC40ZWD2EE
>  9 | Reed    |  9 | user_9  |          9 | HEB34QQH0UM
> 10 | Molly   | 10 | user_10 |         10 | GVP36PLP5PW
> ```

> ```
> explain select
> *
> from myusers
> inner join mytable on myusers.id = mytable.ex_user_id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref                                    | rows | filtered | Extra      
> -: | :---------- | :------ | :--------- | :--- | :------------- | :------------- | :------ | :------------------------------------- | ---: | -------: | :----------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | myusers | null       | ALL  | PRIMARY        | null           | null    | null                                   |   10 |   100.00 | null       
>  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | null       | ref  | idx_ex_user_id | idx_ex_user_id | 5       | fiddle_HNTHMETRTFAHHKBIGWZM.myusers.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=576c37ffccfb4e786c9393f26a128c9f)*

**note** the conversion of user_id from string to integer is "implicit":

> To cast a string to a number, you normally need do nothing other than use the string value in numeric context:
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: Generated column cannot refer to auto-increment column. And id is Auto-increment column.

Comment: @ManishVerma I have re-worked my example, perhaps it will now it will work for you